# mysql check if column is empty with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to check if the row is empty from mysql and perform an operation, but I can't find where I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

my table:`mySQL`

```
id | request |
1  |         |
2  | Example |
```

Following my code:`Php`

```
$checkDescription = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT request FROM wp_request WHERE request=''");

if(!checkDescription ){
echo "Not Null";
}else {
echo "İt's Null"
}
```

Comment: It's `if(!$checkDescription)` you have forget the `$`

Answer (score 0):

Try

> SELECT request FROM wp_request WHERE request is NULL

Comment: I don't keep it as null in the database, I just keep it as empty.

Comment: ?? there is no such thing as empty. Is null or something. Try this sql